# Extract Data from PDF and Import to Excel .NET

Tags: .net, excel, pdf

Is there a sample code or utility which I could use to read PDF documents and convert or export the data into an Excel document?

Most of the sample codes I see when searching are converting Excel to PDF.

Comment: I have found some utility from pdfbox where I use the dlls to extract the text from the pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the PDF probably does not retain any spreadsheet type structure - its just text drawn on a page. So you are unlikely to happy with the results unless its a really simple page.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out data with [pdfsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharp/) and use [openxml sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en) to create an excel file.  That way you will get exactly what you want.  It will take a bit of work, but does not require excel or acrobat or anything that costs money.

Pros:

- Free
- No Excel object model
- Only uses libraries
- You get exactly what you want

Cons:

- Takes time to code it

Answer (score 1):

I've created a solution that uses the combination of the open source XPDF and VBA to import data from multiple PDF files into Excel in a structured format.  It works by specifying start and end text patterns and extracting the text in between with optional replacements for cleaning the output.  The solution can be downloaded freely from http://www.business-spreadsheets.com/forum.asp?t=884

Answer (score 0):

Your only real option here is to look for a third party solution. I doubt you'll find a free SDK that lets you do this either, for the simple reason that it's not that easy. I'd check out [Solid Documents](http://www.soliddocuments.com/) and possibly some of [Investintech's solutions](http://www.investintech.com/).

Newer versions of Acrobat also provide some more advanced PDF to Excel extraction capabilities, so [Adobe's PDF Library SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library/) might be worth looking at too.